# Mutex with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mutex

I have multiple servers sharing a common mongodb. In the DB there is a list of jobs, the servers have to finish. As I want to divide the load over all servers and want to avoid multiple servers doing the same job, I want to "Lock" that job.

My Idea is:

- Set the element as taken if it is not yet taken:

  `db.collection.update({done: false, taken: false},{$set: {taken: true, takenBy: myIp}});`
- Check if the server got the mutex on this element: `db.collection.findOne({taken: true, takenBy: myIp})`

Would that be the best way to "synchronize" multiple worker servers over a mongodb (does the server do updates in a single transaction like mysql) or could the server do multiple of this first commands at once?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274777/mongodb-as-a-queue-service

Comment: This question is more about how mongodb encapsulates single queries and updates (in sql they are called transactions) not about how to build a queue (even when it is the goal to build a queue and that was the reason for the question, I want to know how mongod works under the hood)

Comment: The short answer is that all updates to a single document are atomic. Have you seen http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/?

Comment: Thanks, if you write this as an answer, you get an upvote, I searched for transactions but that probably was the wrong wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key MongoDB feature in this area is that an update to a *single* document is atomic. From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/):

> In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single
>   document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents
>   within a single document.
>
> When a single write operation modifies multiple documents, the
>   modification of each document is atomic, but the operation as a whole
>   is not atomic and other operations may interleave. However, you can
>   isolate a single write operation that affects multiple documents using
>   the [`$isolated`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated) operator.

So for your update of:

```js
db.collection.update({done: false, taken: false},{$set: {taken: true, takenBy: myIp}});
```

this means that it will atomically find a doc that matches the criteria and then update it. So yes, that will work well to assign a task to a given server.

See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274777/mongodb-as-a-queue-service) for more details on implementing a shared work queue in MongoDB. A key point that's mentioned there is the use of [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to both perform the update *and* return the updated doc.