# How to not pick the same object twice while making queries concurrently?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, concurrency, parse-platform

I'm working on a delivery service where I'm processing 8 orders at the same time concurrently, for each of these orders, I must get a unique consignment number that is saved on the database. But since the operations are concurrent, they are all picking up the same object/consignment number.

```js
const query = new Parse.Query("Consign")
        query.doesNotExist("order")
        query.equalTo("staging", staging)
        query.exists("number")
        query.limit(1)
        await query.find().then(function (result) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                order.set("consign_no", result[0].get("number"))
                result[0].set("order", order)
            } else {
                //failed
            }
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
```

How do I make this query in such a way that it picks up unique objects even when ran concurrently?

Comment: I'm not an expert but maybe you find inspiration on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728670/mutex-with-mongodb (that leads you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274777/mongodb-as-a-queue-service ) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer given here by someone else:

- Create a counter collection
- Insert one document into it with `{value:1}`
- Whenever you need a value, use find-and-modify to `$inc` this document and return the new value

This should work (subject to [Is it possible to update the same document on concurrent findAndModify operations in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618314/is-it-possible-to-update-the-same-document-on-concurrent-findandmodify-operation/67620969#67620969)) for giving you distinct values, note that in your documents the values may end up not being consecutive if you insert a value which you retrieved later first.